# can i add key value pair to NSarray or dictionary inside a for loop?

Tags: ios, plist, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

i want to add values to NSMutabledictionary  from a for loop with  key value pairs ?

Currently am using this code

```
for(int j=0;j<[array count];j++){
    for(int l=0;l<array2 count] ;l++){   
          // retreive the category from plist ,then check whether its matching with "catid"
          NSString *temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",allBookPlist[@"listbook"][j][@"cate"][l][@"categories"]];

           if([catId isEqualToString:temp]){    
                 // "catid" is matching with temp then ,retreive the corresponding bid from plist
                 NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",allBookPlist[@"listbook"][j][@"bid"]];
                 // add that  value "bid" and key "catid" to a mutabledictionary
                 NSMutableDictionary *m=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                 [m setValue:str forKey:catId];
            }
     }
}
```

The result is each time the value of the final dictionary "m" get replaced by latest values,but i want all values toghether?

[image] iam trying to get an output like this

Comment: for each `l` you are adding only at index `j`, so it is overwriting each value for key `bid`

Comment: This is not the first time I have to make a similar edit to your posts - please refrain from adding the `xcode` tag when it's inappropriate, thanks.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya :u mean i have to store value outside the second loop?

Comment: This is a logical issue... we dont know for `l` or `j` you need to add a new value.

Comment: outside and inside  loop both are giving same answer

Comment: I said naa, this is logical issue... do you wnat for each l or for each j?

Comment: i want it in this format  catID as main and bid as sub values

Comment: @AnoopVaidya check the image in question

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can move the initialization of the dictionary outside of the for, because in for it got initialised in every loop and that's why it got only one value

```
NSMutableDictionary *m = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for(int j=0; j < [array count]; j++)
{
    NSMutableArray *containerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int l=0;l<[array2 count] ;l++)
    {
        // retreive the category from plist ,then check whether its matching with "catid"
        NSString *temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",allBookPlist[@"listbook"][j][@"cate"][l][@"categories"]];

        if([catId isEqualToString:temp])
        {
            // "catid" is matching with temp then ,retreive the corresponding bid from plist
            NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",allBookPlist[@"listbook"][j][@"bid"]];

            // add that  value "bid" and key "catid" to a mutabledictionary
             [containerArray addObject:str];
        }
        [m setValue:containerArray forKey:catId];
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have updated the code above in order to adapt your output in picture

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
NSMutableDictionary *m=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
for(int j=0;j<[array count];j++)
{
    for(int l=0;l<array2 count] ;l++)
    {
        // retreive the category from plist ,then check whether its matching with "catid"
        NSString *temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",allBookPlist[@"listbook"][j][@"cate"][l][@"categories"]];
        if([catId isEqualToString:temp])
        {
            // "catid" is matching with temp then ,retreive the corresponding bid from plist
            NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",allBookPlist[@"listbook"][j][@"bid"]];
            // add that  value "bid" and key "catid" to a mutabledictionary
            [m setValue:str forKey:catId];
        }
    }
```

I think you are allocating a new dictionary each time inside loop which is not required. Allocate it once & then just keep on adding values to that mutable dictionary.

***I presume, each time you have different `catId` as a KEY***

Comment: syntax errors....ignored! but whatsnew in this code, and how this solves...you need to write those :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop please try this logic

```
NSObject *collectionIndexString = indexPath;
NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [myNSMutableArray[row] mutableCopy];
tempDict[@"collectionIndex"] = collectionIndexString;// Setting Key and Value
[myNSMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:row withObject:tempDict];
```